# Firestore collection listener crashes when editing or deleting document

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have trouble with a firestore listener that listens to an entire collection to set a recoil state. Everything works smoothly when adding a document, but when trying to edit a document or delete it, the database gets updated but the app crashes.

Here is my listener

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getPos();
    const q = query(collection(getFirestore(), "activities"));
    const unsub = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      const activitiesArr: any = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(
        (doc) => {
          activitiesArr.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
        },
        (error: Error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
      setActivities(activitiesArr);
    });

    return () => unsub();
  }, []);
```

The errors I get are

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'ga' of object '#<Dc>'
    at index.esm2017.js:15118
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'fa' of object '#<Dc>'
        at Dc.Ia (index.esm2017.js:15152)
        at Dc.enqueue (index.esm2017.js:15085)
        at Dc.enqueueAndForget (index.esm2017.js:15063)
        at index.esm2017.js:11242
        at Gr.xi (index.esm2017.js:11219)
        at Gr.Oi (index.esm2017.js:10637)
        at index.esm2017.js:10861
        at Y.<anonymous> (index.esm2017.js:10812)
        at qb (index.esm2017.js:27)
        at D (index.esm2017.js:25)
        at Z.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm2017.js.Z.wa (index.esm2017.js:86)
        at sc (index.esm2017.js:42)
        at tc (index.esm2017.js:38)
        at M.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm2017.js.k.Ia (index.esm2017.js:36)
        at M.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm2017.js.k.gb (index.esm2017.js:34)
        at qb (index.esm2017.js:27)
        at D (index.esm2017.js:25)
        at Ed (index.esm2017.js:65)
        at X.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm2017.js.k.cb (index.esm2017.js:64)
        at X.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm2017.js.k.Fa (index.esm2017.js:64)
        at sd (index.esm2017.js:60)
        at qd.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm2017.js.k.Sa (index.esm2017.js:58)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It means that you are mutating some value which is readonly, but I don't see any mutations except `activitiesArr`. Please share `getPos`

Comment: getPos is a function which is only called on the first render and doesn't interact with the database, so it doesn't really has anything to do with the listener and is not run when the app crashes. The app crashes when a change to the database is detected, however, it crashes before the setActivities(activitiesArr) is run.

Comment: Your provided code seems good to me. Your best bet is to debug your code yourself to see where it is exactly crashing. I assume it is in the `activitiesArr.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });` line but it seems good to me. You could try to print in the console the doc.data() for each doc to see if you are properly fetching your documents.